# nslookup for IP & replace the result FQDN with IP

Tags: bash, suse

### Requirement

I have a txt file in which last column have URLs. 
Some of the URL entries have IPs instead of FQDN.
So, for entries with IPs (e.g. url=https://174.37.243.85:443*), I need to do reverse nslookup for IP and replace the result (FQDN) with IP.

### Text File Input

```
httpMethod=SSL-SNI destinationIPAddress=174.37.243.85 url=https://174.37.243.85:443*
httpMethod=SSL-SNI destinationIPAddress=183.3.226.92 url=https://pingtas.qq.com:443/*
httpMethod=SSL-SNI destinationIPAddress=184.173.136.86 url=https://v.whatsapp.net:443/*
```

### Expected Output

```
httpMethod=SSL-SNI destinationIPAddress=174.37.243.85 url=https://55.f3.25ae.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com:443/*
httpMethod=SSL-SNI destinationIPAddress=183.3.226.92 url=https://pingtas.qq.com:443/*
httpMethod=SSL-SNI destinationIPAddress=184.173.136.86 url=https://v.whatsapp.net:443/*
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please do add 3 simple things in your post. 1- What is your question with all requirements. 2- Sample Inputs in CODE TAGS. 3- Expected sample output with what you have tried to get it.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 -- Thanks for the info. I have tried to edit my question & elaborate it. pls let me if it is in correct format now

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty attempt in pure Awk.

```
awk '$3 ~ /^url=https?:\/\/[0-9.]*([:\/?*].*)?$/ {
    # Parse out the hostname part
    split($3, n, /[\/:?\*]+/);
    cmd = "dig +short -x " n[2]
    cmd | getline reverse;
    sub(/\.$/, "", reverse);
    close(cmd)
    # Figure out the tail after the hostname part
    match($3, /^url=https:?\/\/[0-9.]*/); # update index
    $3 = n[1] "://" reverse substr($3, RSTART+RLENGTH) } 1' file
```

If you don't have `dig`, you might need to resort to `nslookup` or `host` instead; but the only one of these which *portably* offers properly machine-readable output is `dig` so you might want to install it for that feature alone.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Within single `awk` after discussion on comments adding this now:

```
awk '
{
 if(match($0,/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)){
   val_match=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);
   system("nslookup " val_match " > temp")};
 val=$0;
 while(getline < "temp"){
   if($0 ~ /name/){
     num=split($0, array," ");
     sub(/\./,"",array[num]);
     sub(val_match,array[num],val);
     print val}}
}
NF
'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** It is my initial solution with `awk` and shell.
Following simple script may help you on same:

```
cat script.ksh
CHECK_IP () {
    fdqn=$(echo "$1" | awk '{if(match($0,/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)){system("nslookup " substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1))}}')
    actual_fdqn=$(echo "$fqdn" | awk '/name/{sub(/\./,""$NF);print $NF}')
    echo "$actual_fdqn"
}

while read line
do
        val=$(CHECK_IP "$line")
        if [[ -n "$val" ]]
        then
                echo "$line" | awk -v var="$val" '{if(match($0,/\/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)){ip_val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1);sub(ip_val,var)}} 1'
        else
                echo "$line"
        fi
done < "Input_file"
```

Comment: That's horrible. Why do you capture stuff into variables just to then `echo` the result back out? The function should use `local` variable with lowercase or mixed-case names, or of course, in this case, no variables at all. Combining the two Awk scripts into one should not be hard, either.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 -- Thank you so much. The script is working perfectly with just few modifications :)

Comment: @tripleee, let me set them to small names now. Also I thought to write it in a single `awk` but then stopped myself thought it could be more harder to understand may be, please let me know your thoughts on same, I am always open to learn from experts.

Comment: @tripleee :- Ravinder's script is indeed working. Though the whole nslookup process is taking a bit. I just ran it on a sample file & the IPs got replaced with FQDNs. 
e.g.

url=https://c8.05.2fa9.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com.:443
url=https://55.f3.25ae.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com.:443
url=https://55.f3.25ae.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com.:443

Comment: @Sid, script is working fine but what Tripleee sir is saying to improve it I believe, which let me work on it as we all are here to learn.

Comment: My comments pertain to efficiency, style, and convention, not to whether the end result is what you expect.

Comment: @tripleee :- Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: I would strive to avoid `echo | awk` in general. Awk can parse the file quicker and more conveniently than `while read`.

Comment: @tripleee, let me write it and add in to it. I also changed the capital letters to small letters variables in function.

Comment: @tripleee :- I agree with you. I also did try to achieve it with awk but ended up with blank results :( .... appreciate your help  if you could improvise.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 -- Cool & thnx

Comment: @Sid, ok added `awk` solution in solution 1st please check and let me know on same, if that works.

Comment: @tripleee, sir, please do let me know if it looks ok now solution 1st.

Comment: There is no need for a temporary file; `getline` can be the destination in a pipe inside Awk. I posted an answer with an example of that just now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 :- Ok....so the solution2 isn't working. The URLs are intact. While for the Solution1 which you had provided initially, when I ran it on a file with all parameters it showed a bit different result. 

returnCode=  CDR_Type=MiepPullWtdr  httpMethod=SSL-SNI   destinationIPAddress=174.37.243.85    url=https://174.37.243.85:443

returnCode=  CDR_Type=MiepPullWtdr   httpMethod=SSL-SNI     destinationIPAddress=55.f3.25ae.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com.      url=https://174.37.243.85:443


basically instead of "url", the "destinationIPAddress" got replaced with FQDN.

Comment: @Sid, both are running fine for me when I tested. You could Tripleee's nice code, if this is not helpful to you. Sorry tried my best to help here

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 :- Its not like your code have any issue. When I am using your code on a file with only 1 column (URLs only)...the code works perfectly but with multiple parameters, the code fails as for each row, the IP in "destinationIPaddress" and "URL" (with IP) are same.

Comment: @Sid, code are always written by seeing your samples so if your actual Input_file is different than shown samples then better to open a new thread as Tripleee and me already spent lot of time on it.